# Force Unix Line endings in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, line-endings

I'm searching for:

- A Visual Studio **2015** option to change default line endings (to Unix style) when writing code inside Visual Studio.
- A Visual Studio **2015** option to change globally all line endings (to Unix style) usefull after copy-pasting text.

I'm working on a international team using different Operative Systems, **and we have to use Unix Line endings**.

Currently I have to use "Advanced Save Options" everytime before committing to remote repository to be sure line endings are Unix, but that is quite uncomfortable.

It seems such feature was requested several times for past VS versions, so did Microsoft ever implemented that and am I missing where is the option?